# Find specific character from string and change its position to previous character using javascript, jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to Find specific character from string and change its position to previous character

for example: Let us say there is say a string: **Kù Iù Mù**

I want output like : **ùK ùI ùM**

Comment: Yes, that's possible.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO.  Please do take the time to read the [tour] and [ask].  Both are linked when you click [Ask Question].

Comment: You just want to switch characters from even posittion to the previous odd position

Comment: Hi and welcome, on Stack Overflow it is generally advised that make an attempt first and ask a question once you get stuck. Can we see the code that you've already tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes of course! You can go over the string in loop char by char, look at the next position and if it is the char U want, switch the position!

```js
function switchChar(text, charToFind) {
  //temp variable for building result
  var result = "";
  //loop over original string
  for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    //chack not to jump out of array
    if (i + 1 < text.length) {
      //if next char is the char im looking for 
      if (text[i + 1] == charToFind) {
        //write next char first
        result += charToFind;
        //then write original char
        result += text[i];
        //iterate i once more to jump over next char (I appended two chars in this single cycle)
        i++;
        //if it is not the char Im looking for
      } else {
        //write it down
        result += text[i];
      }
      //I am at the end
    } else {
      //write the char
      result += text[i];
    }
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(switchChar('Kù Iù Mù', 'ù'))
```

Comment: It was @MaraBlack that made the snippet - I just added the original data to confirm it didn't just do one.

Comment: While this is a fine effort at pure js, personally, I'd go with a regex:  `var x = "Kù Iù Mù"; x = x.replace(/(.)ù/g, "ù$1"); console.log(x)`

Comment: Once I'll be wise enough to understand ancient ruins of the kingdom of Regex, but now is not the time...